# Is it possible to host an aspx (.NET 4.0) website locally on Windows 8 Enterprise?

Tags: asp.net, iis

As the title states is it possibly to host a dynamic (that would be .aspx correct?) website locally (IIS 8) on a computer running Windows 8 Enterprise? I've installed all the IIS components, added the website as many guides on Google will show but I get error 9 as stated here:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055

my web.config is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>  
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also have the correct version set for the site (.NET 4.0) and tried resetting all feature delegations. At this point I'm thinking of just doing a cheese puff solution and just running the site via the built in server within Visual Web Developer.

Comment: Do you have .NET 4.0 or 4.5 installed? By default, Windows 8 comes with .NET Framework 3.5 and .NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services, but I see no mention of .NET 4.0. Also, the error you're getting seems to indicate an error with the Web.config file. Finally, if you're meaning to run a production site on Windows 8 Enterprise, you will only be allowed 10 (or is it 25 now?) simultaneous connections to the computer--it's a limitation of the consumer OS that's lifted on server versions (i.e. Server 2012). HTH.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I actually thought that was the issue for a second but when I tried to install .NET 4.0 it said it was already there (so I have both). I have all the options checked off for IIS in regards to which frameworks are installed. Does the web.config I posted show any bugs that might prevent it from working? The website is actually going to be accessed from a single computer via intranet so that when users walk in they fill out a form and we e-mail that info to be processed.

Comment: See my answer below. Other than missing an `<authentication />` element (which I'm not sure if it's required), your web.config looks good. I suspect something else may be amiss here. HTH, at least in ruling out web.config anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## "Stock" ASP.NET Web.Config file

When I create a standard, empty ASP.Net Web Forms Application targeting .NET Framework 4.0, here's the standard Web.config file that's generated:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections />

  <connectionStrings />

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT:** I removed the Membership, Role, Profile, and SessionState sections that were previously here. These aren't, strictly, required but are part of the standard Empty ASP.Net Web Forms Application template to help you get started quickly. What is shown above is the minimum Web.config you need.

**NOTE:** Don't worry about the `debug="true"` in the `<Compilation />` element. You should have that attribute set to `false` in production anyway.

## I Suspect it's your IIS Configuration

After re-reading your question, I suspect that you haven't properly configured IIS to host the site properly.

First, I want to start by saying that there's Internet Information Services (IIS), the actual web server, that can be installed on Windows 8 as well as server OSes such as Windows Server 2012. There is also *IIS Express*, used for development and which is a replacement for the old Development Web Server (code-named Cassini) in VS2008 and VS2010 (prior to SP1 when IIS Express was made available through an additional installation).

It sounds to me like you have installed IIS under Windows 8 Program and Features. Now you need to create a site in IIS that points to where your web application is located on your hard disk.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Expand your machine name in the **Connections** pane on the left.
3. Expand the **Sites** folder. There should already be a site called *Default Web Site*.
4. Right-click the **Sites** folder and choose **Add Website...**.
5. Give the site a name. Choose the *DefaultAppPool* for now (you can change it later).
6. Under **Physical path**, browse to where your web site/application is located on your hard disk.
7. Click OK.

There are other options on that page and you can find help on them at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com). That may be enough to get you started, though.

Comment: Thank you for guidance as you made me think of a couple things to try. First off I double checked the ASP.NET versions installed and they weren't installed! So I tried to install them again and now the ASP.NET section appeared under IIS. But I ran into another problem. My site sends an e-mail but threw an exception at the line to send the e-mail. I re-added just the authentication section of the "stock" web.config and now that works too.